# DatePickerDialog issue with fragments

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment with editText that is meant to open a date picker. I have done everything seemingly correctly, however I can't figure out why I get the following error.

It has something to do with the fact that I'm working with a fragment.

Could you please help with this error?

[image]

EditProfileFragment.java

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import com.archive.pod.R;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

import java.util.Calendar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class EditProfileFragment extends Fragment {

  //Initializing
  private TextInputEditText mDisplayDate;
  private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editprofile, container, false);

    //EditText
    mDisplayDate = view.findViewById(R.id.etDateOfBirth);

    //Date picker dialog box
    mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
          requireContext(),
          android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_MinWidth,
          mDateSetListener,
          year, month, day);

        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();
      }
    });

    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
        month = month + 1;
        String date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        mDisplayDate.setText(date);
      }
    };
    return view;
  }
}
```

Error Log

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.archive.pod, PID: 20399
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
at com.archive.pod.Profile.EditProfileFragment.onCreateView(EditProfileFragment.java: 33)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java: 2600)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java: 881)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java: 1238)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java: 434)
```

Fragment Layout

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_picture_default"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/changeUserPhoto"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_add_circle"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sectionTitle1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/changeUserPhoto"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/label"
                    android:text="Primary Information"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sectionTitle1">

                <!-- Full name input -->
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/etFullname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                    app:errorEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/full_name" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <!-- Email input -->
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/etFullname"
                    app:errorEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/emailAddress"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sectionTitle2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/relLayout1"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/label"
                    android:text="Private Information"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sectionTitle2">

                <!-- Phone number input -->
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/etPhoneNumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:longClickable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    app:errorEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/phone_number"
                        android:inputType="date"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <!-- Date of birth input -->
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/etDateOfBirth"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/etPhoneNumber"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:longClickable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    app:errorEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/dob"
                        android:inputType="date"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</merge>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just tells you that the first parameter of the `DatePickerDialog` constructor is not as supposed to be; where you put a `Fragment`, while it expects a `context`, so replace below line

```
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
      EditProfileFragment.this,
      android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_MinWidth,
      mDateSetListener,
      year, month, day);
```

with

```
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
      requireContext(),
      android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_MinWidth,
      mDateSetListener,
      year, month, day);
```

Comment: I did as you mentioned however, now I get the following error... mDisplayDate = view.findViewById(R.id.etDateOfBirth);  Unreachable Statment

Comment: Hi @Joe please place `return view;` at the end of the `onCreateView()` method as a last line of code

Comment: Okay I put it there, and the error went away, however now the app crashes. I will update both the code and add the error to the question, in a few sec.

Comment: can you share the fragment layout ?

Comment: now move `android:id="@+id/etDateOfBirth"` from the `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` and put it into its `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`

Comment: if you need explanation, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Use getapplicationcontext() and remove Edittextprofilefragment.this